# Should I place event listeners on the onCreate method or on the onResume method?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a begginer to android development, and I'm trying to add an event listener to a button without using an onClick() in the xml file. Where should I place my event listener and should I remove it somewhere, say, on the onStop method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation of Android, listeners should be added in the OnCreate():
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/input-events

Also, it is not necessary to remove the listeners, since they no longer have a reference when the object is disposed and are thus removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put into onCreate, and it listen, whenever you perform that event.